# How to get installed memory size?

Tags: c, windows

I want to query the installed memory's size. I used the above code:

```
void GetInstalledMemory( char * MemorySize )
{
memset( MemorySize, 0, sizeof( MemorySize ) );

MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;

statex.dwLength = sizeof( statex );

if ( !GlobalMemoryStatusEx( &statex ) ) strcpy( MemorySize, "N/A" );
else sprintf( MemorySize, "%I64d", statex.ullTotalPhys / 1024 / 1024 );

}//GetInstalledMemory
```

The problem with this code is, that under a 32 bit PC it shows 3240 Mb, and under a 64 bit PC it shows 3976 MB RAM, however both PC has 4.0 GB RAM installed. Is there any way to get somehow the installed memory's correct size?

Thanks!

Comment: `sizeof(MemorySize)` is the size of the _pointer_, not how much memory you have allocated for the string. Add a parameter telling the max length of the string to your function.

Comment: For a long time Windows (including 32-bit variants when 64-bit was released) could not address more than around 3 gigabytes of memory, even if you had more. Might be something like that you are seeing.

Comment: Are you sharing your RAM with your video card?

Comment: Even if the RAM isn't used by the video card the address space might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. So, there is really no way to get the installed memory's correct size, because windows in the amount of memory size windows won't calculate the videocard's memory size. So if you have 4 GB RAM installed, and you have a 512 Mb video card, and you want to query the installed memory's size, then you will get as result, the you have ~3488MB RAM. However, from WMI you you can query the correct size. In Win32_PhysicalMemory get value for Capacity and you'll have the correct value.

I know, that WMI query is a complicated a little bit under C, but unfortunately there are some things, that you can query only from there. In my application, i'm making right now, i already use wmi querys, so it's not a problem for me.

Thanks everyone for your help!

kampi

Answer (score 3):

This code might work,

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX m;
    m.dwLength = sizeof (m);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&m);
    printf("Installed Memory size = %I64d KB\n", m.ullTotalPhys/1024);
    return 0;
}
```

But hardware accessing functions are not in *standard C*. So they wont be portable.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589.aspx)

### **UPDATE**

> The problem with this code is, that under a 32 bit PC it shows 3240 Mb, and under a 64 bit PC it shows 3976 MB RAM, however both PC has 4.0 GB RAM installed.

This is because **32 bit machine can not address more than 3Gb memory.**

Comment: If you're dividing by 1024, then you're not reporting *bytes*.

Comment: Fixed it. Didn't test the code. Just grabbed it from MSDN. :D

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the DMI interface and would be limited to systems that support it. Many versions of Windows (including XP and Vista with no service packs) have no idea how much physical memory is present.

Comment: How is windows then able to report an installed memory size on its information page? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Find-out-how-much-RAM-your-computer-has

Comment: @RedX That page is Windows 7. It's not the first feature that's been added to Windows.

Comment: @Daniel But if i go to my "Computer -> properties" i can see a description of my CPU + Clock + amount of memory available to Windows XP.

Comment: @RedX I doubt you have an XP with no service packs running, so if David meant it to be parenthesized 'including (XP and Vista) with no service packs',  he could still be right.

Comment: @Daniel oh, i see now what he meant. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Obviously Windows XP knows the amount of memory available to Windows XP. This question is about the amount of physical memory installed. The OP knows how to get the amount of memory available to the OS (the 3240 and 3976 in his question).

Answer (score -1):

Neither ANSI/ISO C nor POSIX allow you to query the size of installed main memory, the rationale being that it makes no sense for your program logic to depend on the amount of installed RAM. The following two generic workarounds do however fairly well, especially when combined:

- allocate as much as you need and complain if there's not enough memory available
- ship your code/program with a notice that reads: "Requirements: at least  MB of main memory"

Comment: How does this answer the OP question in any way?

Comment: "The purpose of computing is insight, not numbers." (R. W. Hamming)

Comment: "...but for the student, numbers are often the best road to insight." (A. Ralston)